# How to apply pagination in Lumen?

Tags: laravel, lumen

How can I make my page paginated so that it shows 10 records/page. I have done this in Laravel but not sure how to do it in Lumen

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Paginate is available in Lumen. You will do just the same as in Laravel. Here is the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#basic-usage

I have myself used it in version 5 of Lumen and I can tell you that it works the same.

ex.
`$users = DB::table('posts')->paginate(10);`

Comment: Thanks, wish you had answered earlier.

Comment: How to add the page links in android app?

Answer (score 9):

## skip / take

To limit the number of results returned from the query, or to skip a given number of results in the query (**OFFSET**), you may use the `skip` and `take` methods:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset