# How can I add pagination in Lumen 8 collection?

Tags: laravel, api, pagination, response, lumen

I am using Lumen to create api where I integrate collection. All code details are given below. I want to add pagination according to my code. How I add paginator in my code?

In Controller:

```
//To get all Employee Type
public function getAllEmployeeTypes(){

    $employeeType = OsEmployeeType::where('status',1)->orderBy('priority', 'DESC')->get();
    return new OsEmployeeTypeCollection($employeeType);
}
```

In Collection it looks like

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection->map(function($data) {
            return [
                'id' => $data->id,
                'name' => $data->name,
                'priority' => $data->priority,
                'status' => $data->status,
            ];
        })
    ];
}

public function with($request)
{
    return [
        'success' => true,
        'status' => 200
    ];
}
```

and the response that I got

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Type 3",
        "priority": 3,
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Type 2",
        "priority": 2,
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Type 1",
        "priority": 1,
        "status": 1
    }
],
"success": true,
"status": 200
```

}

How can I paginate my API response?

Comment: [how to apply pagination in lumen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022756/how-to-apply-pagination-in-lumen)

Answer (score 0):

Paginate is the same as Laravel in Lumen. You will do just the same as in Laravel.

```
    $employeeType = OsEmployeeType::where('status',1)->orderBy('priority', 'DESC')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$employeeType = OsEmployeeType::where('status',1)->orderBy('priority', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?